# rotation is reset when I playback animation

Tags: objects

[image] Rotation of a propeller, impossible to change the axis

Comment: It would help if you would clarify your question and setup and maybe even post your blend file.  However at a guess you have keyframed the rotation of your propeller, when you change the axis you are not updating the keyframes, so it returns to the keyframed values when you hit play.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I understand, the movement of the propeller don't know the orientation of the plane. How I do for fix the orientation of the propeller and keep his movement.

Comment: You are using keyframes. Moving the object without updating the keyframes  will make the previously set keyframes remain unaffected.

Comment: How I do for update keyframe ?

Comment: @Vincent One way would be to use another empty.  I assume you have parented your propeller to the empty and keyframed the rotation of the empty.  You could create Empty 2 and parent Empty 1 to Empty 2.  Rotate  Empty 2 to change the axis.

Comment: Thank you for the way, it's a little bit strange, but It's true.Thank you for answer @risingfall

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the image above., the animation is recorded on the Empty. I assume but cannot tell for certain that all 3 rotations are animated. you only need a single rotation to be animated.

You can remove the other 2 keyframes from the axis you don't need to be animated and it will fix the issue.

[image: Image showing all 3 axis are locked]

The yellow color means that there are keyframes present for these properties.
You should remove them. For example I assume that the rotation around the X-axis is the one you want to keep.

Press other mouse button on the Y and click on `Clear Single Keyframes`. Do the same for the Z.

[image]

This will remove the keyframed animation on the Y-rotation and the Z-rotation.

Comment: If you see the plane there is the rotation of the propeller (360°) I have no problem with this mouvement. But the propreller have a angle with the plane. I can use my keyframe in a normal way XYZ in global.

Answer (score 0):

[image: The plane and the propeller rotation]

**2 Empty** is the solution one for 360° and a second for match the plane with her.